# Exception executing JS code from C#: Function expected

Tags: javascript, c#, string-parsing, comparison-operators

I have this javasccript expression code as a string in my C# code, I need to evaluate it (execute it) using Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate (c#) and get result back.

```
string code = @"var roles=[];
roles.push('LOC_IND');
roles.push('MANAGERL3');
var country='CANADA';
var age=80;
eval(""roles.indexOf('Administrator')>=0||roles.indexOf('LOC_IND')>=0&&country=='CANADA'"")";

// Calling JScript.Eval to execute that code
var engine = Microsoft.JScript.Vsa.VsaEngine.CreateEngine();
var result = Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate(code, engine);
```

The javascript code itself **works fine**, if you execute it in browser console, and returns "true", as expected:

```
var roles=[];
roles.push('LOC_IND');
roles.push('MANAGERL3');
var country='CANADA';
var age=80;
eval("roles.indexOf('Administrator')>=0||roles.indexOf('LOC_IND')>=0&&country=='CANADA'")
```

However, when I call it from C# Eval.JScriptEvaluate(code, engine); I get this exception:

> **Function expected.**

I am not sure what function it expects and what do I have to do to fix that?
At the end Eval.JScriptEvaluate(code, engine) must return true.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Why does it use `eval()`?

Comment: It's obvious, it has to evaluate the expression, run it in browser console, you will see.

Comment: It works with `eval()` but it also does exactly the same thing *without* `eval()`.

Comment: One thing I note is that as posted here, there's a line break in the middle of that string you pass to `eval()`, and that's an error in JavaScript.

Comment: Where? dont see any line breaks

Comment: With eval or without, I still get "Function expected" error from  Eval.JScriptEvaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot doggy :)

I found an easier way, using another library - Jint.

This location is the right one: https://github.com/sebastienros/jint

```
string code = @"var roles=[];
roles.push('LOC_IND');
roles.push('MANAGERL3');
var country='CANADA';
var age=80;
function foo(){return roles.indexOf('Administrator')>=0||roles.indexOf('LOC_IND')>=0&&country=='CANADA';}";

// Using Jint - Javascript Interpreter for .NET

var result = new Jint.Engine().Execute(code).Invoke("foo");
```

P.S. Another option is to use self-invoking function, but it is more difficult to get to the return bool result:

```
string code = @"var roles=[];
roles.push('LOC_IND');
roles.push('MANAGERL3');
var country='CANADA';
var age=80;
(function(){return roles.indexOf('Administrator')>=0||roles.indexOf('LOC_IND')>=0&&country=='CANADA';})();";

var result = new Jint.Engine()
    .Execute(code)
    .Boolean
    .PrototypeObject
    .PrimitiveValue
    .AsBoolean();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to call eval.
Second, you should wrap your code in a self invoking function because you're expecting a single result.
Third, looks like Microsoft JScript doesn't support some or all the methods of JavaScript's Array.prototype, so you can't use indexOf().
Try this code:

```
string code = @"
function hasRole(roles,role){
    for(var i=0;i<roles.length;i++)
        if(roles[i]==role)return true;
    return false;
};
(function(){
    var roles=[],country='CANADA',age=80;
    roles.push('LOC_IND');
    roles.push('MANAGERL3');
    return hasRole(roles,'Administrator')||hasRole(roles,'LOC_IND')&&country=='CANADA';
})();";
```

On a side note, it looks like you're missing a pair of brackets in your return statement.